# Invalid grant received when making request

Tags: java, authorization, access-token, refresh-token

Sometimes I'm getting `{"error":"invalid_grant"}` while making a request to an external api from my java application.

First I'm making an authorization request using grant_type as `'password'` which contains u`sername,` `password`, `clientId` and `clientSecret` and it works correctly.

Later based on that response which contains an access_token and refresh_token I'm trying to make another authorization request using grant_type as 'refresh_token' but it fails with the above error message. I already tried to get informations about the situations which may lead to this error from the external api support but I didn't get anything. Is there a way to find out what am I possibly doing wrong with my request?

The requests are made using apache `CloseableHttpClient`.